# share the current image viewflipper

Tags: android

I want to share the current image being viewed from the viewflipper, but I can not get the name of the image being displayed, this is the code I use:

```
public class imagen1 extends Activity {
    public float init_x;
    private ViewFlipper vf;

    int gallery_grid_Images[] = {R.drawable.fondo, R.drawable.fondo2, R.drawable.fondo3,
            R.drawable.fondo4, R.drawable.fondo5
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.imagen1);
        ImageView imagePreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.preview);

        vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
        for (int i = 0; i < gallery_grid_Images.length; i++) {
            //  This will create dynamic image view and add them to ViewFlipper
            setFlipperImage(gallery_grid_Images[i]);
        }
        vf.setOnTouchListener(new ListenerTouchViewFlipper());

    }

    private void setFlipperImage(int res) {
        Log.i("Set Filpper Called", res + "");
        ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        image.setBackgroundResource(res);
        vf.addView(image);
    }

    public void compartir (View v) {

        Uri newUri2 = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
                + "/drawable/" + gallery_grid_Images);
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, newUri2);
        shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Compartir"));

    }
}
```

If someone could help me a little would greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this should do the trick for you:

```
public class imagen1 extends Activity {
public float init_x;
private ViewFlipper vf;

int gallery_grid_Images[] = {R.drawable.fondo, R.drawable.fondo2, R.drawable.fondo3,
        R.drawable.fondo4, R.drawable.fondo5
};

ImageView[] views = new ImageView[gallery_grid_Images.length];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.imagen1);
    ImageView imagePreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.preview);

    vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
    for (int i = 0; i < gallery_grid_Images.length; i++) {
        //  This will create dynamic image view and add them to ViewFlipper
        setFlipperImage(gallery_grid_Images[i], i);
    }
    vf.setOnTouchListener(new ListenerTouchViewFlipper());

}

private void setFlipperImage(int res, int index) {
    Log.i("Set Filpper Called", res + "");
    ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    image.setBackgroundResource(res);
    vf.addView(image);
    views[index] = image;
}

public void compartir (View v) {
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
        if (views[i] == (ImageView) vf.getCurrentView())
            index = i;
    }

    if (index == -1) {
        // failed to determine the right index
        Log.w("imagen1", "Could not determine the right index!");
        return; 
    }

    Uri newUri2 = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
            + "/drawable/" + gallery_grid_Images[index]);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, newUri2);
    shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Compartir"));

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I've used it just a few times, but as far as I know the viewflipper just show one of its childs at a time. You should call this method in order to show a child:

```
viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(childPosition);
```

The loop in your code will just set the last image of your array, if you'd rather to show a list of images you should go for a RecyclerView/ListView.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

works perfectly, you do not know how much I appreciate your help, I only had to modify a part in the code because it gave me error:

```
Uri newUri2 = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
            + "/drawable/" + gallery_grid_Images[i]);
```

add Index

```
 Uri newUri2 = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
                + "/drawable/" + gallery_grid_Images[index]);
```

Thank you so much for your help